# How to Get Posts, Including Private Ones?

Tags: posts, get-posts

Currently in one of my php files, I retrieve all of the public posts like this:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post'
));
```

However, this only returns *public* posts, and I would like to store all posts, both public and private, in the `$posts` variable. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set [the `post_status` argument](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#status-parameters) to an array of desired post status strings, or to the string `any` to query regardless of status entirely:

```php
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'post_status'    => array( 'publish', 'private' ),
));
```

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem :) . Consider [accepting the answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) to mark the question as resolved